# Notation of injective hull $(0 :_E p^k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If $R$  is a Noetherian ring and $p$  is a prime ideal, set $E = E(R/p)$  as the injective hull.
Now it is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Computing_injective_hulls)
clamed that
the injective hull of $R/p$ over the Artinian ring  $R/p^k$  can be computed as the module
$(0 :_E p^k)$.

What does the notation mean? I know that $(J:I)$ denotes the  [ideal quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient). What does the subnotation $_E$ mean inside $(0 :_E p^k)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $M,N$ are submodules of some $R$-module $U$, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then
$$
(N:_MI):=\{m\in M\mid I\cdot m\subseteq N\}
$$
is the "colon module".  This is just the natural generalisation of the colon ideal $(J:I)$ where the $:$ would now have the subscript $R$ (which isn't doing anything so we drop it again).

Here, the subscript $E$ is the $E=E(R/\mathfrak{p})$, the injective hull of $R/\mathfrak{p}$ in the first sentence of the paragraph.  Then $(0:_E \mathfrak{p}^k)$ is the submodule of $E$ that is annihilated by $\mathfrak{p}^k$, and $(0:_E\mathfrak{p}^\infty)=\bigcup_d(0:_E\mathfrak{p}^d)$ is the submodule of $E$ consisting of everything in $E$ that get annihilated by some power of $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: That's quite strange, because if I try to apply this definition,
I get a nonsense result, could you look through my calculations? 
 Since $R/p$ is integral domain, 
the injective hull $E = E(R/p)$ is $K:= Frac(R/p) $
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_hull#Examples), right?

Now we want to compute  injective hull of 
$R/p$ over $R/p^k $. How does act $K$ by multiplication
on $p^k \subset R$? Isn't the multiplication *always* zero
because $R/p \subset K$? But then $(0 :_E p^k)$ equals
for every $p^k$ to the complete $E= Frac(R/p) $. Isn't this strange? Or did I somwhere a error?

Comment: @IsaktheXI Be careful!  The injective hull $E(R/p)$ is $K=\operatorname{Frac}(R/p)$ in the category of $R/p$-modules, not in the (larger) category of $R$-modules.  If you look at the Prufer group example, $E(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ in the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules is the $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ah, that's the essential point. So in general if we take arbitrary integral domain $R$ and and for any prime $p$ consider the injective hull of $R/p$ over $R$ (!) then in general it's a hard business to compute the hull, of does there exist a general theory classifying the injective hulls of exactly the quotient rings of such form $R/p$?